# How to link a form inputs to each other

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have a form that has multiple inputs. Like parent and child.

1. Activity 1
   1.1 Sub-activity 1
   1.2 Sub-activity 2
   1.3 Sub-activity 3
2. Activity 2
   2.1 Sub-activity 1
   2.2 Sub-activity 2
   2.3 Sub-activity 3

These parents and child are generated dynamically. By this I mean that I can create multiple of them by clicking on add more button with jQuery .

My question is that how should I save them that when I want to fetch it back from database then every child should be under its parent.

I am using laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by name attribute of any input field.

```
name="field_name[1][]"
name="field_name[2][]"
```

for multiple inputs you can refer to https://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/

and while displaying them in the edit form you can just loop through all the elements to create your tree like structure.

Comment: Can you please make it more clear. Please show it in the form format and how to save it into database using laravel.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
1.name="activity1"

  1.1.name=['activity1']['Sub-activity 1']
  1.2 name=['activity1']['Sub-activity 2']
  1.3 name=['activity1']['Sub-activity 3']

2.name="activity2"

   2.1.name=['activity2']['Sub-activity 1']
   2.2 name=['activity2']['Sub-activity 2']
   2.3 name=['activity2']['Sub-activity 3']
```

here name means input field name so you need to arrange names like this depending of your input field.

Comment: Now the question is that how I should save it in to database using Laravel framework.